# Can a multiple dimension array be passed as a single pointer parameter?

Tags: arrays, parameter-passing, c++14

```
int f(char* x)
{
    //something
}
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    char arr[4][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    f(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't expect how many dimensions of an array a programmer is going to pass. So I want to let this function get a multiple dimension array as a single parameter. Is it possible?

Comment: You'll need some information about the dimensions. You can pass it, but it won't be useful unless you know what is there. Maybe you should consider making a class that wraps your data and includes meta information that the programmers must provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using templates to deduce the size of the array:

```cpp
template<const std::size_t rows, const std::size_t cols>
int f(char (&arr)[rows][cols])
```

Your full code would look like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
template<const std::size_t rows, const std::size_t cols>
int f(char (&arr)[rows][cols])
{
    //something
}
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    char arr[4][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    f(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

This might also be helpful: [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the number of *dimensions* of the array, you'll have to get creative:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<T>::value, int> = 0>
void f(T &arr) {
    constexpr auto dimensions = std::rank<T>::value;

    std::cout << "Received array with " << dimensions << " dimensions!";
}
```

You can use [`std::rank`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) and [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) to retrieve information about the array's geometry.

[See it live on Coliru!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b90209b75e3e911)

Comment: Thank you. I'm really glad to know that there's what outputs the number of dimensions of an array.